# Accessibility:; Form Label error even with a corresponding id in select menus

Tags: forms, select, label, accessibility, screen-readers

Having problems on a Shopify site with issues regarding labels relating to select menus. Both Lighthouse and axe claim there's errors regarding these labels even though I have the label id related to the one in the select tag. Here's an example page: https://boxiecat.com/collections/litter where both the All Types and Featured menus are not validating. I should mention I don't want the text to appear in the label except for people with screen readers. Thus the sr-only style which is set in my CSS to display: none;. Here's an example from one of them:

```
<label for="c"><span class="sr-only">Select collection</span></label>
<select id="c">
  <option value="/collections/all" selected="selected">All types</option>
    <option value="/collections/types?q=" ></option>
    <option value="/collections/types?q=Litter" >Litter</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `display: none` will hide the labels from assistive technology. You’ll want to visually hide that [using another css technique](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/).

Comment: @steveax Thanks for providing that link. So what do you normally do? Seems the negative text-indent method is the way to go, but I’m open to hearing yours (or anyone’s) method.

Answer (score 1):

While I would argue that visible labels increase usability for all users, if the design insists upon no visible labels, there are two main ways to provide labels for assistive technology: include the label elements and visibly hide them through CSS, or add `aria-label` properties to the form control.

For the CSS solution, the [clip method detailed here](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#techniques) works well in my experience:

```
{
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

If you’re confident that your users employ [assistive technology that supports the `aria-label` property](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/), you can [add the labels through that property](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA6.html)

Comment: +1 for the answer - although "if the design insists upon no visible labels" - you should add that if this is the case it is the design that needs changing and the designer needs to realise that labels are essential for people with cognitive impairments such as anxiety disorders.